# error - require is not defined . How to write a json file with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, require

I want to make a level editor for my platformer game with phaser and I am saving the data in json files. I want to write json with javascript and I searched then i came to know that we can write it first writing this `const fs = require("fs")`   and many more but on this line I get error require is not defined. I want to create a json file. I using it in the browser with windows 7. how can I use require to do so.

If there is any other way to write json file with js, then please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` doesn't exist on the browser/client side. Also, you cannot use `fs` as well, it should be implemented on the back-end side. Please use the following approach -

```
function download(filename, json) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + JSON.stringify(json));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```